# Hom Tensor Adjunction for Ext Groups

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, derived-functors

Let $X$ be a scheme with structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$. Then for $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules $\mathcal{F},\mathcal{M}, \mathcal{N}$ there exist a natural Hom- Tensor adjunction

$$ Hom_{\mathcal O_X}(\mathcal{F},  Hom_{\mathcal O_X} (\mathcal{M}, \mathcal{N})) =  Hom_{\mathcal O_X}(\mathcal{F} \otimes_{\mathcal O_X} \mathcal{M}, \mathcal{N})$$

My question is:

If we consider the derivated functors $Ext_X ^n(\mathcal{F}, -)$ of the functor $Hom_{\mathcal O_X}(\mathcal{F}, -)$, does hold the similar formula

$$Ext_{X} ^n(\mathcal{F},  Hom_{\mathcal O_X} (\mathcal{M}, \mathcal{N})) =  Ext_{X} ^n(\mathcal{F} \otimes_{\mathcal O_X} \mathcal{M}, \mathcal{N})$$

?

Background of my question is the red tagged line in following excerpt from "Vector Bundles on Complex Projective Spaces" by Christian Okonek,
Michael Schneider, Heinz Spindler:

[image]

$Ext_{\mathbb{P}^1}^1(F, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1})=H^1(\mathbb{P}^1, F^* \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1})$?

My ideas:

I know because of $F^*= Hom_{\mathbb{P}^1}(F,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1} )$ that 
$$H^1(\mathbb{P}^1, F^* \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1})= Ext_{\mathbb{P}^1}^1(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}, F^*)= Ext_{\mathbb{P}^1}^1(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}, Hom_{\mathbb{P}^1}(F,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1} ))$$

Futhermore $$Ext_{\mathbb{P}^1}^1(F, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1})= Ext_{\mathbb{P}^1}^1(F \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1})$$

To conlude $Ext_{\mathbb{P}^1}^1(F, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1})=H^1(\mathbb{P}^1, F^* \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1})$? it would be nice if $Ext_{X} ^n(\mathcal{F},  Hom_{\mathcal O_X} (\mathcal{M}, \mathcal{N})) =  Ext_{X} ^n(\mathcal{F} \otimes_{\mathcal O_X} \mathcal{M}, \mathcal{N})$ holds.

Does it? If yes, how to see it?

Comment: No there is no such isomorphism $\operatorname{Ext}^n_X(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{H}om(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N})=\operatorname{Ext}^n(\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N})$ in general because we would like to take account of the derived $\mathcal{H}om$ and the derived tensor product. However, there is such an isomorphism if $\mathcal{M}$ is locally free.

Comment: Well, how can I otherwise see that $Ext_{\mathbb{P}^1}^1(F, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1})=H^1(\mathbb{P}^1, F^* \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1})$ holds?

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread the text. This is a weird notation, because there is no use to tensor with $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}$. I'll remove my comment.