# $Ext_{\mathbb{P}^1}^1(F, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1})=H^1(\mathbb{P}^1, F^* \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1})$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

My question refers to a step in the proof of THM 2.1.1 (Grotherdieck) from excerpt from "Vector Bundles on Complex Projective Spaces" by Christian Okonek, Michael Schneider, Heinz Spindler (page 12):

[image]

Why does hold

$$Ext_{\mathbb{P}^1}^1(F, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1})=H^1(\mathbb{P}^1, F^* \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1})$$

In my former thread [Hom Tensor Adjunction for Ext Groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2745195/hom-tensor-adjunction-for-ext-groups)

I tried to proof a statement that had been instantly provided wished equality, but the statement was wrong, so I wasn't able to apply it.

How to show the statement above otherwise?

Answer (score 3):

For any locally free sheaf $E$ and any quasi-coherent sheaf $F$ over some scheme $X$, we have $Hom_X(E,F)\cong Hom_X(\mathcal{O}_X,E^\wedge\otimes F)$ where $E^\wedge$ denotes the dual sheaf of $E$. Taking derived functors of both sides and noting that $Hom(\mathcal{O}_X,-)=\Gamma(X,-)$, we obtain the result.

Comment: The point being that an injective resolution $I^\cdot$ of $F$ gives an injective resolution $E^\wedge\otimes I^\cdot$ of $E^\wedge\otimes F$. Correct?

Comment: Also, we don't need $F$ to be locally free...

Comment: Yes, your comments are correct.

Comment: Under which conditions does this statement hold: $I $ injective resolution of $F$ then $E^\wedge\otimes I^\cdot$ is an inj resolution of $E^\wedge\otimes F$? Should $E^\wedge$ have special properties? Locally freeness?

Comment: @KReiser - we don't even need $F$ to be q-c...

Comment: @KarlPeter I think the arg is: 1) The fact that $E^\wedge$ is locally free (because $E$ is) means that tensoring with $E^\wedge$ is exact. 2) since $E$ loc. free, one has $\mathop{\text  {Hom}}( G, E^\wedge\otimes I) = \mathop{\text  {Hom}}(G \otimes E, I)$. Therefore  $E^\wedge \otimes I$ is injective if $I$ is. Therefore $E^\wedge \otimes I^\cdot$ is an injective resolution of $E^\wedge \otimes  F$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Tho remarks: I suppose that $\mathop{\text  {Hom}}( G, E^\wedge\otimes I) = \mathop{\text  {Hom}}(G \otimes E, I)$ also holds if $E^\wedge$ is not loc free, or is this wrong?

Comment: Secondly: If I understood your argument correctly then having $\mathop{\text  {Hom}}( G, E^\wedge\otimes I) = \mathop{\text  {Hom}}(G \otimes E, I)$ in mind you would use following characterisation of injectivity:

Comment: $I$ is injective iff for  every $f: A \to B$ the induced map $Hom(B,I) \to Hom(A,I)$ is surjective. Having $\mathop{\text  {Hom}}( G, E^\wedge\otimes I) = \mathop{\text  {Hom}}(G \otimes E, I)$ I can always switch between Hom to show the surjectivity above for every given $f$. Or do you apply the argument $\mathop{\text  {Hom}}( G, E^\wedge\otimes I) = \mathop{\text  {Hom}}(G \otimes E, I)$ in another way here?

Comment: @KarlPeter  1) I had in mind your 'injective iff surjective' argument. As for your other (first) question: 
bear in mind for modules)that (*) $\text {Hom} ( A \otimes B, C) = \text{Hom} (A, \text{Hom} (B,C ) )$ always holds. 
But  - $\mathbb Z$-modules (a.k.a ab. groups): say $N={\mathbb Z}/ 5{\mathbb Z}$. Then $0 \ne \text{ hom }( N, N)$. 
However $ 0 = \text {hom} (N , {\mathbb Z} )\otimes N$.  So we need some kind of condition on $N$. (cont)

Comment: @KarlPeter 2) Now, it seems to me that (*) should hold for sheaves 
(with internal hom as needed), with (notation as here) no condition on $B$. But Hartshorne exercise 5.1 assumes loc. free finite rank - hmn. 3) BTW, you should use the 'at' sign when addressing people: I didn't get the 'red' flag because there are more than the two of us in the comments.

Comment: @KarlPeter - btw: I was sloppy in my very first comment to you (earliest one today): I am 'of course' assuming $E$ is loc. free of FINITE rank... Also I meant Hartshone exercise 5.1, of chapter II